# why am i getting undefined for match object in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The below code is to update a product in admin panel. I have manage to do everything except that on a button pressed for update i want to fetch the url from the above address bar. I thought of using match.params.productId. Here produtId is what i wanted ti get. But i dont know why the match object returns undefined..PLease help me to get rid of this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Base from "../core/Base";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  getAllCategories,
  getProduct,
  updateProduct
} from "./helper/adminapicall";
import { isAuthenticated } from "../auth/helper/index";

const UpdateProduct = ({ match }) => {
  const { user, token } = isAuthenticated();

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    price: "",
    stock: "",
    photo: "",
    categories: [],
    category: "",
    loading: false,
    error: "",
    createdProduct: "",
    getaRedirect: false,
    formData: ""
  });

  const {
    name,
    description,
    price,
    stock,
    categories,
    category,
    loading,
    error,
    createdProduct,
    getaRedirect,
    formData
  } = values;

  const preload = (productId) => {
    getProduct(productId).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
      } else {
        preloadCategories();
        setValues({
          ...values,
          name: data.name,
          description: data.description,
          price: data.price,
          category: data.category._id,
          stock: data.stock,
          formData: new FormData()
        });
      }
    });
  };

  const preloadCategories = () => {
    getAllCategories().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
      } else {
        setValues({
          categories: data,
          formData: new FormData()
        });
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log(match);
    preload(match.params.productId);
  }, []);

  //TODO: work on it
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, error: "", loading: true });

    updateProduct(match.params.productId, user._id, token, formData).then(
      (data) => {
        if (data.error) {
          setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
        } else {
          setValues({
            ...values,
            name: "",
            description: "",
            price: "",
            photo: "",
            stock: "",
            loading: false,
            createdProduct: data.name
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };

  const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    const value = name === "photo" ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;
    formData.set(name, value);
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

  const successMessage = () => (
    <div
      className="alert alert-success mt-3"
      style={{ display: createdProduct ? "" : "none" }}
    >
      <h4>{createdProduct} updated successfully</h4>
    </div>
  );

  const createProductForm = () => (
    <form>
      <span>Post photo</span>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="btn btn-block btn-success">
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("photo")}
            type="file"
            name="photo"
            accept="image"
            placeholder="choose a file"
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          onChange={handleChange("name")}
          name="photo"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={name}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <textarea
          onChange={handleChange("description")}
          name="photo"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Description"
          value={description}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          onChange={handleChange("price")}
          type="number"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Price"
          value={price}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <select
          onChange={handleChange("category")}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Category"
        >
          <option>Select</option>
          {categories &&
            categories.map((cate, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={cate._id}>
                {cate.name}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          onChange={handleChange("stock")}
          type="number"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Stock"
          value={stock}
        />
      </div>

      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={onSubmit}
        className="btn btn-outline-success mb-3"
      >
        Update Product
      </button>
    </form>
  );

  return (
    <Base
      title="Add a product here!"
      description="Welcome to product creation section"
      className="container bg-info p-4"
    >
      <Link to="/admin/dashboard" className="btn btn-md btn-dark mb-3">
        Admin Home
      </Link>
      <div className="row bg-dark text-white rounded">
        <div className="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
          {successMessage()}
          {createProductForm()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Base>
  );
};

export default UpdateProduct;
```

Comment: `match` is a passed prop. Where is `UpdateProduct` rendered? Is it as a `component`, `render`, or `children` prop of a `Route` component within a `Router`? If not as one of those, is it decorated with the `withRouter` HOC? Can you update and include your router code?

Comment: UpdateProduct is rendered at ManageProductts where an admin can manage products like updating and deleting. When the user press the update button it renders the UpdateProduct.js

Comment: This tells nothing of conditions in which `UpdateProduct` is rendered. Where is `match` passed as a prop?

Comment: {match} is passed in UpdateProduct function and rendered in useEffect

Comment: No, `match` is passed as a prop in the function signature `const UpdateProduct = ({ match }) => {...`. The question is ***what*** is passing `match` to `UpdateProduct`? You `export default UpdateProduct;` so presumably you aren't using the `withRouter` HOC, so `UpdateProduct` needs to be rendered as `component`, `render`, or `children` prop of a `Route` component in order to receive the `match` prop.

Comment: nothing. I have just used the match as it is as i destructured in the function signature. I read this in some docs. My goal is to read the productId from the address bar something like hhtp://localhost/admin/product/userId/productId . So i read that  the match object has  params which could help me to read the address. PLease suggest me something

Comment: *Something* (presumably) is rendering `UpdateProduct`, so somewhere, some component between a `Route` rendering a component and `UpdateProduct`, has an opportunity to receive and pass on a `match` prop. If `UpdateProduct` isn't being rendered directly by a `Route`, then perhaps an ancestor (parent) component is. Can you trace that path to find where a `match` prop exists? Sharing the router code is just a super simple way of telling how your routed components are being rendered.

Comment: can you provide me your mail id? Ill mail you the codes

Comment: No thank you. You can share a link in your question if getting the code shared here is cumbersome.

Comment: preload component is rendering the match ... useEffect(() => {
    //console.log(match);
    preload(match.params.productId);
  }, []);

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5Djwrm    I have shared two code files in this link.Please check it.

Comment: I don't see anything rendering `UpdateProduct` component in your codeshare.